# davening mincha before shkia

Tags: tefilla

Why do most ashkenazic jews accept and follow the  Vilna Gaon's Zman of davening mincha before shkia when they don't follow the gra on many other things he requires?

Comment: It's hard to think of a rabbi about whom we don't sometimes follow them and sometimes not. Why is this so unique that you ask about it? Please edit to clarify

Answer (score 4):

Besides for the fact we hardly ever follow every single p'sak of anyone (Rova/Abeyai, Beis Hillel/Beis Shammai all have exceptions), the Gr'a's zman for mincha is originally that of the Talmedei Rabenu Yonah, so following it does not necessarily mean following the Gr'a as such.

Comment: [Welcome to Mi Yodeya](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks very much for the great answer! Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting. Can you [edit] your post to add a source to your claim that this zman originated with the Talmidei Rabbeinu Yona? Thanks :)